# I want to disable end date picker before choosing start date picker in react js

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to disable the end date picker until the user enters the start date? Below I am sharing my code. Please tell me where I am doing wrong?

```
const startDate = new Date();    
<Controller control={control} name="start_date" render={({ field }) => (
    <DatePicker placeholderText="MM/dd/yyyy" dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
    onChange={(date) => field.onChange(date)}  minDate={moment().toDate()}
    selected={field.value}
    id="start_dates"
    required={true}
    autoComplete='off'
    onKeyDown={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    }} />)}/>
    
    <Controller control={control} name="end_date"  render={({ field }) => (
    <DatePicker dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
    onChange={(date) => field.onChange(date)}  
    disabled={startDate=== ""? true: false}
    minDate={new Date(startDate)}
    selected={field.value}
    
    onKeyDown={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); }} />)}/>
```

Comment: which library for `DatePicker` you are using?

Comment: import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

Comment: is this condition not working on enddate `disabled={startDate=== ""? true: false}` ?

Comment: not working this condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create state variable `dateStart`.

In `onChange` event of `startDate` set its value, then disable `endDate` based on `dateStart` like this:

```
const [dateStart, setDateStart] = useState(null);
```

StartDate datepicker

```
<DatePicker placeholderText="MM/dd/yyyy" dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
    onChange={(date) => field.onChange(date); setDateStart(date)}  
    minDate={moment().toDate()}
    selected={field.value}
    id="start_dates"
    required={true}
    autoComplete='off'
    onKeyDown={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    }} />)}
 />
```

EndDate datepicker

```
<DatePicker dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
    onChange={(date) => field.onChange(date)}  
    disabled={dateStart ? false : true}
    minDate={new Date(startDate)}
    selected={field.value}
    
    onKeyDown={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); }} />)}
/>
```

Working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-datepicker-example-forked-l3l64o?file=/src/index.tsx)